# Can I add a group of classes as delegates to groovysh

Tags: groovy, groovysh

When I run groovysh I'd like to add some classes so they execute as though they were delegates.  It should work like this:

assuming these classes exist:

```
def A{
   def test() {println "test"}       
}

def B{
   def test2() {println "test2"}
}
```

I'd like to be able to do this:

```
groovysh
groovy:000>test()
test
groovy:000>test2()
test2
```

I might be able to scan the classes and manually add each method to the groovy.properties file but that would be extremely fragile.

Is there some way to either specify those classes as delegates or somehow make it act as though I had done something equivalent to:

```
new A().using{new B.using{ <groovysh runs in here> }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so good answer:

I just realized that one possible answer is to :load a script that looks like this:

```
classA=new A()
classb=new B()
test=classA.&test
test2=classB.&test
```

This isn't a very good answer because I'd need to create those method references for each method I wanted to expose, but since it would work I thought I'd post it.

EDIT--another poor answer

Another possibility would be to make the methods all static and do a static import of each class.  This is better but I'd have to refactor all the classes I want to load... still not awesome.

I hope someone posts something better.